# I am trying to use my terminal and to make my website contact form work but I see this. I don't understand what it means

Tags: installation, static-libraries

I wrote this because I am following a tutorial class§. I opened visual studio code with my public folder with my website files. I opened my terminal and wrote this npm i express.js nodemon nodemailer dotenv

It says its invalid.
My package json version is version: (1.0.0)

Comment: Welcome! Please paste the exact wording of the error that you see in your terminal

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.